# how to find probability of exponential distribution question?

Tags: statistics

The time until failure of cell phones follows an exponential distribution with a mean of 20,000 hours.

Consider a random sample of 12 cell phones. What is the probability that at least 4 of them fail within 10,000 hours of use?

answer: 0.761

I know the probability of one cell phone failing within 10,000 hours is 0.3935 by doing: $$\int^{10000}_{0} \dfrac{1}{20000} e^{-\dfrac{1}{20000}x} dx$$
I'm unsure how to find at least 4 cell phones failing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cell phone is an independent "trial" with the probability of failure given by the integral you computed. So you can use the binomial distribution to solve the problem.